# Is 'm' a common instance for Master and Fellow classes in this runtime polymorphism scenario?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at programming stack and, I have a small question to ask based on these code lines.

Is 'm' a common instance for Master and Fellow classes in this runtime polymorphism scenario?

```
class Master{
    void something(){
        System.out.println("Something of Master");
    }
}

class Fellow extends Master{
    void something(){
        System.out.println("Something of Fellow");
    }
}


public class Drive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Master m = new Fellow();
        System.out.println(m instanceof Fellow); //true
        System.out.println(m instanceof Master);  //true
        m.something(); // Something of Fellow
```

Answer (score 2):

`m` is an instance of `Fellow`. Because `Fellow extends Master`, *every* instance of `Fellow` is also an instance of `Master`.